# Can I create a property of a property?

Tags: vb.net, class, methods, properties, visual-studio-2012

So I recently grasped the concept of using classes in my Visual Basic programming, and I found it tremendously helpful. In my current project, I have several groups boxes of check boxes (each check box denotes a "Behavior") and in each group box, there is always one check box that has a textbox control **instead of a label** (to allow the user to specify an "Other" behavior). It is that user-generated label that is giving me trouble...

I created a class called "Behaviors" that basically does the following:

1. getChecked > This method gets each checked checkbox and adds it to
   the BehaviorCollection for a given Form.
2. behaviorCollection > represents the collection of checked
   checkboxes.
3. getOtherChecked > does the same as "getChecked" except with the
   "Other Behavior" checkboxes.
4. otherBehaviorCollection > represents the collection of checked
   "Other" checkboxes.

The issue is that for each checked "Other Behaviors" checkbox, I need to store the value of its corresponding textbox. I would like to set my getOtherChecked() method to do this, so that in the end, I would be able to something like this...

```
Dim myBoxes as new Behaviors
Dim cBox as Checkbox
Dim cBoxLabel as String

myBoxes.getOtherChecked(myUserForm) 'This would get each checked "Other Behaviors" checkbox object, and also somehow add another property to it called "LinkedTextboxLabel" that would be assigned the value of the corresponding textbox.
cBox = myBoxes.otherBehaviorCollection.item(0) 'Assign a checkbox from my "Other Behaviors" collection to a variable.
cBoxLabel = cBox.LinkedTextboxLabel 'Assign the user-inputted value of the linked textbox to a variable.
```

So basically how could/should I add a custom-property to a collection item or checkbox?

I thought about just adding the names of the controls to a temporary DataTable or SQL table, so that each row would have the name of a checkbox in one column and its corresponding textbox value in the next, but I am hoping there is a more commonly used and accepted method.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Great question! Deserved an up vote & Favorite.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property for the text associated with the "Other Behaviors" checkbox.

EDIT: You might be trying to generalize your data too far, because the "Other behaviors" is a special case and deserves separate consideration.

If you have a look at what the following code (in a new Windows Forms project) creates, it might give you ideas:

```
Public Class Form1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A behaviour domain and its characteristics, with one user-defined entry.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Class BehavioursSectionDescriptor
        Property BehaviourTypeName As String
        Property BehaviourNames As List(Of String)
        Property CustomBehaviours As String
    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Return a GroupBox containing CheckBoxes and one Checkbox with a TextBox adjacent to it.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="behaviourSet"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function GetBehaviourGroupPanel(behaviourSet As BehavioursSectionDescriptor) As GroupBox

        Dim gb As New GroupBox
        gb.Text = behaviourSet.BehaviourTypeName

        Dim fixedBehaviourNames As List(Of String) = behaviourSet.BehaviourNames
        Dim customBehavioursValue As String = behaviourSet.CustomBehaviours

        Dim cbVertSeparation As Integer = 4
        Dim gbPadding As Integer = 20

        Dim cb As New CheckBox

        Dim yLoc As Integer = gbPadding

        For i = 0 To fixedBehaviourNames.Count - 1
            cb = New CheckBox
            cb.Location = New Point(gbPadding, yLoc)
            cb.Text = fixedBehaviourNames(i)
            ' you can use the .Tag Object of a Control to store information
            cb.Tag = behaviourSet.BehaviourTypeName & "-Cb-" & i.ToString()
            gb.Controls.Add(cb)
            yLoc += cb.Height + cbVertSeparation

        Next

        cb = New CheckBox
        cb.Text = ""
        cb.Location = New Point(gbPadding, yLoc)
        cb.Tag = behaviourSet.BehaviourTypeName & "-Custom behaviours"
        gb.Controls.Add(cb)

        Dim tb As New TextBox
        tb.Location = New Point(gbPadding + 18, yLoc)
        tb.Width = 100
        tb.Text = customBehavioursValue
        gb.Controls.Add(tb)
        ' make sure the textbox appears in front of the checkbox's label area
        tb.BringToFront()

        gb.Size = New Size(160, yLoc + gbPadding * 2)

        Return gb

    End Function

    Private Function GetTestData() As List(Of BehavioursSectionDescriptor)
        Dim bsds = New List(Of BehavioursSectionDescriptor)
        bsds.Add(New BehavioursSectionDescriptor With {.BehaviourTypeName = "In water", _
                                                     .BehaviourNames = New List(Of String) From {"Floats", "Spins"}, _
                                                     .CustomBehaviours = "Paddles"})

        bsds.Add(New BehavioursSectionDescriptor With {.BehaviourTypeName = "Under light", _
                                                     .BehaviourNames = New List(Of String) From {"Shines", "Glows", "Reflects"}, _
                                                     .CustomBehaviours = "Iridesces"})

        bsds.Add(New BehavioursSectionDescriptor With {.BehaviourTypeName = "Near food", _
                                                     .BehaviourNames = New List(Of String) From {"Sniffs", "Looks"}, _
                                                     .CustomBehaviours = ""})

        Return bsds

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim bsds As List(Of BehavioursSectionDescriptor) = GetTestData()

        Dim gbs As New List(Of GroupBox)
        Dim xLoc As Integer = 20
        Dim yLoc As Integer = 20

        ' make some GroupBoxes to present the data input fields
        For i = 0 To bsds.Count - 1
            Dim gb = GetBehaviourGroupPanel(bsds(i))
            gb.Location = New Point(xLoc, yLoc)
            gb.Dock = DockStyle.None
            yLoc += gb.Height + 30
            Me.Controls.Add(gb)
        Next

        ' size the form to fit the content
        Me.Size = New Size(240, yLoc + 40)

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: This can't be done because the corresponding textbox acts as the label for this checkbox. The checkbox text value should be blank.

Comment: @Lopsided I added some code which shows how you can incorporate a custom element.

Comment: This did actually give me an idea. I could throw each "Other" checkbox into a panel with only its textbox counterpart. Then I could very easily reference each like this panelName.Controls(0) for checkbox and panelName.Controls(1) for textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't answer the question of adding a property to a property, but could you create a class for the Other checkbox and override it's capabilities?  Then you could add checkboxes and OtherCheckBoxes to your generic collection?  for instance,  (by no means complete, but you should get the idea)

EDIT: Changed code to show Shadows

```
Public Class OptionalCheckbox : Inherits CheckBox
Private mOptionalText As String

Public Shadows Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return mOptionalText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        mOptionalText = value
        MyBase.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

For each item, if you were to retrieve .Text, you would either get your textbox value or your checkbox label (if it was a normal checkbox)

And how to utilize in other parts of your code.  Again, this is just more of an example.  You would still need to work with the textbox that is assigned to the OtherCheckBox to get it to write the text to that, as well as read from that into the .Text property of the Class.

```
    Dim newCheckBoxCollection As New Collection

    Dim cBox As New CheckBox
    cBox.Text = "Standard Value Here"
    'other properties of the checkbox can be modified here
    newCheckBoxCollection.Add(cBox)

    Dim cOBox As New OptionalCheckbox
    cOBox.Text = "Optional Text Here"
    'other properties of the checkbox can be modified here
    newCheckBoxCollection.Add(cOBox)

    For Each cb As CheckBox In newCheckBoxCollection
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cb)
    Next
```

Comment: This looks really good. I've seen specific overrides like this before but have never delved too far into their use. I'll be trying this tomorrow and mark this correct if it works! Thanks again.

Comment: This hasn't worked for me :/ The IDE won't let me use Overrides here, it says I need to use shadows. I spent a couple hours reading up on overrides, shadows, widening operators, derived and base classes, but nothing seems to work. I've found a solution for this particular project, but I would still like to see a successful example of creating a property of a property...or of replacing a type like you suggested.

Comment: I changed the code above to give you an idea of how the Shadows works.  It of course needs more work to make it work for you (such as getting it to read/write from the textbox), but if you paste this into the IDE, you should get the idea.  Another idea would be to create a user control that takes a Checkbox or OptionalCheckBox control as a property and then do what you need it to do.  (display the textbox, hide the checkbox text, etc.).  Think of a user control as a class that has a visual element to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just save the data into something like a DataTable or SQL table the code would be a bit of an overkill. I suggest you use a stream reader/writer and try checking the values that way as the code would be a lot more simple.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm unfamiliar with streaming reader/writers, but will start reading up on it now. Funny, properties within properties doesn't seem like an uncommon need . . . Hopefully some VB guru can show how it is done :)

Comment: Yeah they are very useful alright, I use them all the time :) Handy for saving settings forms :) Yeah I hope one comes along :L

Comment: Not going to work here, but I like the idea of using this to save settings. +1 on the comment haha